# Add views block to views header

Tags: blocks, views

I want to have the views header elements after exposed filters, so i try to get the filters in the header. For that, i expose them in a block, and try to add that block to headers, but no success. I also tried to show the filters-block on the view's page (an admin path) via the block settings (show in content area, only on pages admin/content/myview), also no success.

To add a generic block to a views header via UI, there's the module
https://www.drupal.org/project/views_block_area

On the module page it says

> Blocks that are generated by views, can't be selected. These blocks can be inserted by views areas.

But i can't see how to do that. When i add a view area to my view's header, i have the view which generates the exposed-filters block, but the block is not listed, only the default and an attachment i have in that view.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that is to modify your View template. Identify it in the third column (Advanced), section Theme : informations (by default views-view.tpl.php). Find it (usually in sites/all/modules/views/theme). Then you will just have to reorganize this tpl file. In your case, you just need to switch two sections like this :

```
<?php if ($exposed): ?>
<div class="view-filters">
  <?php print $exposed; ?>
</div>
```

```
<?php if ($header): ?>
<div class="view-header">
  <?php print $header; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for (php-)coding-free way, to do that. You say 'easyest way'... so, might there be a way through the admin ui? Maybe a hack with some css, or moving html via js? Sounds ugly...

Comment: Actually, I would have proceeded just like you, at first sight. By exposing your filters in a block and configuring the block (in the right theme region, only on page "your-view-url") so it would appear before the complete view and thus the view header. I can not tell why it did not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Add views block to views header: Drupal 8/9/10

This can be done from backend by voew UI

Install & enable [twig tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) module

Edit particular view & click on header section, add following code:

```
{{ drupal_view('view_name', 'display_name') }}
```